# Escaping characters in JavaScript run inside of a PHP Wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, wordpress, shortcode

I came across this weird scenerio. I was writing a shortcode which executed some jQuery stuff, specifically parsing an XML file (`jQuery.parseXML()` -this turns the XML file into a jQuery object). It came down to me trying to get the text from inside an XML tag called < captions.file >, which I attempted to do this:

```
var captionsFileURL = (JQXML.find("captions\\.file")).text();
```

According to a StackExchange post I found, the period in the name of tag needed to be escaped so it wasn't interpreted as a tag called `captions` of class `file` (but why is it double escaped?). This worked when I tried it manually in the console, but not with the javascript in the shortcode. I then tried escaping it again:

```
var captionsFileURL = (JQXML.find("captions\\\.file")).text();
```

...and it worked. I'm trying to understand why all this escaping needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question (why is it double escaped?), here is the explanation:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

From here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

As for why you needed to add an extra (third) slash to the above selector, I don't know - probably either within the parsing or in some transformation afterwards an extra slash was added to the original string. Should see the whole code snippet to be sure.